# ko.Observable array contains data but it's length property has value as 0

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a ko.observablearray.I'm populating with some values I get from the server:

```
self.AllItems = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON('/Controller/GetItems', function (data) {
   for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
   self.AllItems.push(data[index]);
   }
 };
});
```

I know this much works fine as I have the array bound to list and that contains all the items.

```
<select multiple="multiple" size='4' data-bind="options:$root.AllItems, selectedOptions:$root.ItemsSelectValue"> </select>
```

However, I'm not able to access any of the elements of AllItems afterwards.
`alert(self.AllItems().length);` -- returns 0

`alert(self.AllItems());` -- returns nothing

Please help.

Comment: Your code should work. Exactly when are your alerts executed in the `$.getJSON` callback after getting the data? Can you maybe create a reporo in JSFIddle?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `alert` *after* `getJSON` returns data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to mimic the server call in Fiddle..

Comment: yes, the sequence of the calls are alright.

Comment: `function (data)function (data) {` ?? what about `function (data) {` ??

Comment: Sorry, a copy paste error. Corrected that.

Comment: Where did you call alert(self.AllItems().length); ? Since getJSON works async you have to call it inside callback function.

Comment: @ArtemVyshniakov I just discovered that for myself. Since the call happens asynch, my AllItems doesn't contain data as of when I try to access it's properties. Moved the alert inside the callback and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: stupid question, but you applying your bindings right?

Comment: Is it working with replacing the first line to: `self.AllItems = ko.observableArray(['Opt1', 'Opt2', 'Opt3]);`? I'm trying to make sure if the problem is bound to the way you use async getJSON.

Comment: @Nanda The code you posted in the question [is working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ84f/). You should help us [reproduce](http://sscce) the issue, otherwise it's a guessing game (as is clear from prior comments :D).

Comment: @Nanda for improving performance don't push single items to your observable array. Instead populate another non-observable array and use `ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.AllItems, nonObservableArray)`. Your solution will re-render UI each time item is added to an observable collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely trying to alert the value of `AllItems` before the (asynchronous) jQuery Ajax call has completed. You can get around this by making use of [jQuery XHR promises](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), such as the `done` promise:

```
self.AllItems = ko.observableArray([]);

// Perform the XMLHttpRequest, and store the XHR object in a variable
var getItemsXHR = $.getJSON('/Controller/GetItems', function (data) {
  for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    self.AllItems.push(data[index]);
  }
});

// Wait for the XMLHttpRequest to finish before reading AllItems
getItemsXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert(self.AllItems().length);
  alert(self.AllItems());
});
```